# Ubuntu touch phone close the connection with ubuntu-sdk

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

Last week i installed Ubuntu touch 16.04 in nexus 4 and i had a connection problems between my Ubuntu-sdk and my device when i run an application (maybe ssh problem).

```
error: Could not connect to host: The remote host closed the connection
Is the device connected and set up for network access?
```

Can someone give me a solution and thanks.

Comment: 16.04? What channel? You should use _stable_ or _rc-proposed_ on mako.

Comment: I used devel channel "ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu"

Comment: That is out of date and not meant to be used. You need to switch to stable or rc-proposed for the channel on the device, and use a 15.04 kit in the SDK.

Comment: There is a bug in the 15.04 kit. I can't use Qt multimedia module and the classes of QT 5.5.

Comment: That's not a bug. The phone is based on 15.04 and uses Qt 5.4.1. The devel, devel-proposed, and similar channels are not really supported. They were being built as a test to ensure that images were still building with newer Ubuntu versions. Building a C++ app for those targets, and trying to run it on 15.04 stable phones, won't work.

Comment: when  i run my application in phone, there is a bug when using QCamera  class, i don't know where is the bug but there is a bug at least when using this class "QCamera"

Comment: So make a question describing that problem, and it can be determined if it's a bug you should report, or if there is some other problem.